# Why is $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \oplus \mathsf{P}$?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I have a very basic question. $\mathsf{P}$ is the class of decision problems solvable in polynomial time by a Turing machine. $\oplus \mathsf{P}$ is the class of decision problems solvable by an NP machine such that

1. If the answer is 'yes,' then the number of accepting paths is odd.
2. If the answer is 'no,' then the number of accepting paths is even.

How do you show that $L \in \mathsf P \implies L \in \oplus \mathsf P$? i.e., that $\mathsf{P} \subseteq \oplus \mathsf{P}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can think of a deterministic Turing machine as a nondeterministic Turing machine which doesn't make any nondeterministic choices, and so has a unique execution path. Consequently, a deterministic Turing machine has at most one accepting path. It accepts an input if there is an accepting path, and it doesn't accept an input if there is no accepting path. In particular, it accepts an input iff the number of accepting paths is odd.

Comment: Thank you! I still don't understand something though. If the input accepts, I understand that a deterministic Turing machine will accept in polynomial time by definition and that nondeterminstic TMs generalize deterministic ones. But how do we know that there aren't multiple accepting paths that aren't "seen" by the deterministic TM? I think there's something fundamental that I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Deterministic Turing machines make no nondeterministic choices. There is a single run of the machine, which is either accepting or rejecting.

Comment: Ah, I see. To decide if $x \in L$ for some $L \in \oplus P$, we are deciding if there exists any nondeterministic Turing machine such that the number of accepting paths is odd. In the case that $L \in \mathsf{P}$ we can just give the deterministic one which has one accepting path iff $x \in L$. And, $x \not\in L$ iff there are zero accepting paths (if that weren't the case, then the deterministic TM would have accepted). Thanks, your original answer makes perfect sense now.